# Decode JWT received from /v2/authorize

Tags: oauth2, authentication, jwt

I'm developing an app for SalesForce Marketing cloud.

For the authentication I have a web page loaded as iframe in the salesforce mc; in this page the customer performs the login to my platform. After the login I redirect the user to /v2/authorize in order to get the authCode.

/v2/authorize redirects to my backend service passing a JWT (that should contain the authCode, client_id, eid, stack_key etc...); this JWT has a strange format, in fact its parsing give me this exception:

```
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The token was expected to have 3 parts, but got 4.
```

The JWT received has 3 "dots" instead the standard 2.

Example:

```
header:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.

payload:
<hidden_data>.

signature:
CTU8Pj4viXit1LGXxyvFVUxXdv6d9tQy2JGDREzaAzo.

???
kZPYXe04Hx5MsxoOCL1PUy3QzopmD4e_KIVqoZjePU7m-1ku0ytvSs0TZLW5JXIsECSx00DjZ4IMGTRnzX6FbXbMKAxjIIABYYO8U6rRBQMSPpB0LWoNA5TXIbr3B31OjfY_7f1lyfCkr3G9JhPXOhMxVY_uEUAMvyR4i_7FClkGbca0khgGrHWgz
```

What I'm missing? Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up two flavors of the authorization available in MC - the so-called "[legacy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/single-sign-on.htm)" flow which relied on JWT and the newer [oAuth-based flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-app-auth-code.htm) which do not rely on JWT. (The core SF platform underneath Sales Cloud et al **does** support auth flows with tokens encoded as JWTs). The legacy flow has been retired as of August 1, 2019. `/v2/authorize` is part of a newer flow and the oAuth access token that is returned in the last step of the flow is not a JWT. It does have periods but it's an opaque token and it cannot be decoded a la JWT.

Note for completeness: a JWT with an encrypted payload has 4 periods (5 encoded segments).